# How to identify a popup Window in Internet Explorer using BluePrism?

Tags: popupwindow, blueprism

I try to identify the popup window from IE in the application modeller using accessibility mode, But I get an error saying "There was an error during the spying operation." what should I do to solve that problem ???
Please Help!!

Answer (score 0):

it can often happen, that the popup window cannot be spied in the same object as the main application.

The solution is to create a new object and attach it is to the window that appeared. I've automated webpages, that had 3 appearing windows, and each one required a different object! The simplest one that I had to code, was a single pop-up window, that needed to have "ok" clicked.

Comment: I have try to do it in another object but also it isn't working, i would to code it but i hadn't know how, i'm a beginner in blueprism, can you send me your code please, thanks.

Comment: Well, if that will help you, then please see below a link to simplest object that attaches itself to popup from internet explorer.

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/778e31eefa130f2feac9cb7e5e2b707320171109105316/eec9fd

Comment: thanks, i will try it after and i respond to you if it work well